# Spring Batch Hello World

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I'm trying to do [this Spring batch tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-batch/spring-batch-hello-world-example/)

But I'm getting the following error relating to the `jobRepository`.

I've read that the `jobRepository` is mandatory when creating a job but I don't know why it's not being created. I've loaded all my dependencies as per the tutorial.

Could somebody help point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

```
Jun 03, 2017 8:13:18 PM 
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext 
    prepareRefresh
    INFO: Refreshing 
    org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@579bb367: 
    startup date [Sat Jun 03 20:13:18 AEST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
    Jun 03, 2017 8:13:18 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring/batch/jobs/job-hello-world.xml]
Jun 03, 2017 8:13:18 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory registerBeanDefinition
INFO: Overriding bean definition for bean 'helloWorldJob': replacing [Generic bean: class [org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.xml.SimpleFlowFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] with [Generic bean: class [org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.xml.JobParserJobFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null]
Jun 03, 2017 8:13:18 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@3532ec19: defining beans [report,itemProcessor,org.springframework.batch.core.scope.internalStepScope,org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomEditorConfigurer,org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.xml.CoreNamespacePostProcessor,step1,helloWorldJob,cvsFileItemReader,xmlItemWriter,reportMarshaller]; root of factory hierarchy
Jun 03, 2017 8:13:18 PM org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller createJaxbContextFromClasses
INFO: Creating JAXBContext with classes to be bound [class com.mkyong.model.Report]
Jun 03, 2017 8:13:18 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry destroySingletons
INFO: Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@3532ec19: defining beans [report,itemProcessor,org.springframework.batch.core.scope.internalStepScope,org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomEditorConfigurer,org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.xml.CoreNamespacePostProcessor,step1,helloWorldJob,cvsFileItemReader,xmlItemWriter,reportMarshaller]; root of factory hierarchy
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'step1': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jobRepository' while setting bean property 'jobRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'jobRepository' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:329)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1393)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1134)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:608)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at com.mkyong.App.main(App.java:18)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'jobRepository' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:568)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1102)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:278)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:323)
    ... 15 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: As a side note, that tutorial is *very* dated.  I'd recommend using the guide provided at spring.io: https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/

Answer (score 0):

First of all, that seems a too complicated tutorial for category - "Hello World".

Secondly, if you are starting now, you shouldn't use XML based configurations - Use annotations based configuration unless you have very compelling reasons to do so - find a Java Configuration based tutorial.

Regarding your error, if you go down that tutorial , in context.xml, he is defining repositories ,

```
<!-- stored job-meta in memory -->
    <!--
    <bean id="jobRepository"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean">
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    </bean>
     -->

     <!-- stored job-meta in database -->
    <bean id="jobRepository"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
        <property name="databaseType" value="mysql" />
    </bean>
```

You have not shown any code, so I can't be sure as what you are missing.

If you are not using any DB , use commented out bean - `MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean` but you will have to make sure that some in - memory DB like HSQL , H2 are on your class path. These dependencies are not there.

If you have a mysql database, use existing beans as shown in context.xml and mysql dependency is included.